# I am getting an error message as "Object Required" when trying to calculate value from differnt sheets and write on summary page

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting an error message as "Object Required" for the below code.

I wanted to calculate the total count of "Passed" status from different sheets 
and write that value in the "Dashboard" sheet in the same workbook.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim row As Integer

row = 15
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then
    Dashboard.Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('" & sh.Name & "' !E:E,""Passed"")"
End If
row = row + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I found the answer for my problem :

```
  Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim row As Integer
Dim var As Integer



row = 15
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then
    var = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(sh.Name).Range("E:E"), "Passed")
    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D" & row).Value = var

End If
row = row + 1
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. To address worksheet, you must enclose its name in worksheet object, like Worksheets("NameofSheet") . Also, there were unnecessary `'` in your formula.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim row As Integer

row = 15
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

If sh.Name <> "Dashboard" Then

    Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & sh.Name & "!E:E,""Passed"")"
End If
row = row + 1
Next
```

Comment: now getting an error as "Run Time error 1004 : Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: Is there any additional code running? because this code should not give you an error...?

Comment: I have created multiple macro's but executing only one at a time ... is it causing the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (remove the 2 ' and kill the blank between the " and the !

```
    Dashboard.Range("D" & row).Formula = "=COUNTIFS(" & sh.Name & "!E:E,""Passed"")"
```

Comment: strange as it works ok for me. But I have to admit that your final solution with '= WorksheetFunction....' is definitely better!